# Network Days In Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I need to create network or working days in Tableau on the below expression.
I have created network days on a different calculation but not sure how should i link it here.
The code is:

```
if ISNULL([Resolved Date])   
then TODAY()- [Pending Date] // 1st condtion    
ELSEIF ISNULL([Pending Date]) and [Resolved Date] !=NULL  
THEN  
[Resolved Date]-[Assigned Date] // 2nd condition   
ELSEif ISNULL([Pending Date]) and ISNULL([Resolved Date])   
then   
TODAY()- [Assigned Date]  
else  
[Resolved]
```

How to do i remove weekends from the above formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, posting for the benefit of other users

```
ABS(if ISNULL([Resolved Date])
then  (DATEDIFF('day',TODAY(),[Pending Date]) - (DATEDIFF('week',TODAY(),
[Pending Date])*2))
ELSEIF ISNULL([Pending Date]) and [Resolved Date] !=NULL
THEN
(DATEDIFF('day',[Resolved Date],[Assigned Date]) - (DATEDIFF('week',
[Resolved Date],[Assigned Date])*2))
ELSEif
(ISNULL([Pending Date]) OR  ISNULL([Resolved Date]) )
then
(DATEDIFF('day',[Assigned Date],TODAY()) - (DATEDIFF('week',[Assigned 
Date],TODAY())*2))//DATEDIFF('day',[Assigned Date],TODAY()) 
else
(DATEDIFF('day',[Resolved Date],[Pending Date]) - (DATEDIFF('week',[Resolved 
Date],[Pending Date])*2))//[Resolved Date]-[Pending Date]
END)
```

Answer (score 0):

This [Interworks blog post](https://www.interworks.com/blog/jbajon/2015/11/10/questions-tableau-training-business-day-calculations) describes how to find the difference between two dates without counting weekends. It doesn't address the issue of holidays.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this link](http://meowbi.com/2016/09/19/business-hours-calculation-in-tableau/) to calculate business days with option to specify single holidays and business start and end hours.